# QML Custom List Data type

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm wondering if it is possible in QML to define a custom list class that can be used in QML.

Currently, I'm parsing more or less complex data structures and translating them into a tree of QVariantMap, QVariantList and QVariants.
However, these types may include rather large arrays of most basic types (uint8_t, uint16_t, ..., uint64_t, int8_t, ..., float, double).
I'd prefer it if I didn't have to copy these arrays into a QVariantList for obvious performance reasons.
Is there any way I can wrap the array in a custom type that provides item access in a way QML understands and thus only copy the elements to a QVariant when requested?

I've tried registering a type with a `Q_INVOKABLE operator[]` but that doesn't seem to work.

**Update:**
To clarify a bit more. I know I can create a class with custom properties that could provide accessor methods. However, with the QVariantList method I can do the following in QML

```
onMessage: {
  element.text = message.poses[0].position.x
}
```

I'm looking for a way to wrap the array such that the actual implementation is not noticeable in QML, meaning, it should look like a normal array which can be accessed with the bracket operator etc. The fact that it is actually just a wrapper should be completely transparent to the user.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data ? Also, what do you want to do with these data (display, processing, etc.)?

Comment: It's a library hence the data and use case can differ from user to user but it's usually a tree structure, for example it could be a pose which contains two members: a position and an orientation. The position consists of an x, y and z which are the leafs (e.g. Floats). But it may also contain an image which is a pretty big array. Personally, I can't think of many use cases where the array data is needed in QML but I'd prefer not to limit the use cases if possible.

Comment: Obviously, I don't want to copy large arrays to qvariantlist since in most use cases they aren't accessed anyway but I'd like to give the option to access their content, hence, I'm looking for an option to wrap the array so it can be accessed from qml without copying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your array in a `QObject` and pass it as a context property to the QML part.

For example, to use a vector of integers in QML:

```
class ArrayInterface: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    using value_t = int;
public:
    ArrayInterface(std::vector<value_t> const& src): QObject(), source(src)
    {}
    // Can be called from QML
    Q_INVOKABLE int get(int idx) const
    {
        return source[idx];
    }
private:
    std::vector<value_t> const& source;
};
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    std::vector<int> vec = {12, 4, 5, 7};
    ArrayInterface data(vec);

    QQuickView view;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myArray", &data);
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

```
Item {
    height: 500
    width: 500
    Text { text: myArray.get(0) }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do know about context properties. I'm sorry, I should have been more specific and have updated the question. I want the QML side to act exactly as if it was a QVariantList / a JS array. The fact that the array is wrapped for lazy loading should not be noticeable to the user.

Comment: You can't use operator for your C++ ojects in QML (I guess, because JS doesn't support operator overloading). You can only call functions. But, you can wrap `QVarianList` and have only a function `get()` or `at()`.